# Pimp my UAC and a few questions about it

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, windows-vista, uac

I have this application that need to do some things in protected paths (like %PROGRAMFILES%), I know that I should be using %APPDATA%, but I can't change that for now. I have isolated all the things that could require UAC to show up on another project, here's a sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Class1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            File.CreateText(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "something.txt"));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "UnauthorizedAccessException", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "not again";
                proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                proc.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exit to avoid loop.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I call this executable from my main program, and if it fails because of an unauthorized access, it will launch itself showing the UAC request.

My questions are:

1) I had to convert the project output from a DLL to an EXE because I couldn't find any way to request UAC elevation from a DLL, is there any easy way to do that?

2) I also noticed that some programs show a personalized UAC message, with the program logo and all those things, let me show you an example:

[image: Ugly UAC]

[image: Personalized UAC]

How can I do that for my program?

3) To avoid entering in a loop when is running with elevated privileges an it gets another UnauthorizedAccessException I did that thing passing any args. What would you do to achieve the same goal?

I think that's all for now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Regarding the colors, those depends on the program. See http://news.softpedia.com/images/news2/Windows-Vista-UAC-Colors-3.png for a quick rundown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 you can not control the elevation mode of the process hosting your DLL. You can [grant permission to the target folder or registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379588(VS.85).aspx) for everyone [during the install process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d.aspx) if you can control install process.

2 you need to [sign the program with a certificate published by a certificate authority that would be trusted by the client](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/50a72eb8-298b-4302-9651-aed0169de1c9/). Visit your local certificate store (control panel->internet options, content tab, publishers) to see common certificate authorities.

3 when you get UnauthorizedAccessExceotion, throw it to the hosting exe or return an error value indicating a security problem. The caller of your DLL then decide what to do, such as displaying a security error dialog to inform the user if the program is already elevated (permission not granted by domain controller?) , or [restarting the process in elevated mode using the runas command](http://blogs.msdn.com/vistacompatteam/archive/2006/09/25/771232.aspx) if it is not elevated.

Answer (score 6):

I had same problems. Googling around about 2 days I found the only solution that fit my needs - start the application with administrative rights. I start the application, check if it being run as admin. And if doesn't - **restart** it with administrative rights.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (NeedElevation(args) && Elevate(args))
        { // If elevastion succeeded then quit.
            return;
        }
        // your code here
    }

    public static bool Elevate(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo;
            info.Verb = "runas";
            info.Arguments = NoElevateArgument;
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                info.Arguments += ' ' + arg;
            }
            info.FileName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;

            Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo = info;

            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You don't have administrative privileges thus the Automatic Application Updates cannot be started. But the rest of application is available as usually.",
                "Not enough user rights", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```