# How to set DACL of a Windows service so that a normal user can start / stop the service

Tags: installshield, dacl

I have a Windows service application whose installer I am building using install shield. How to set the DACL of the service while installing?
I know I can do a "sc sdset" after installing. But I want to set the elevated permissions as part of the install process. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after the installation run this command as part of post installation procedure:
SUBINACL /SERVICE  /GRANT=S-1-5-32-545=TO

This gives the  windows service the admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have properly created installation your your service. The following resource may be helpful to confirm that: [Using InstallShield to Create an Installation that Installs Windows Services](http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/2014/10/updated-support-creating-an-installation-that-installs-windows-services-.html) as well as InstallShield help library: [Installing, Controlling, and Configuring Windows Services](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/installshield21helplib.htm#StartTopic=helplibrary/FAQFilesNTService.htm).

I am not sure if DACL settings can be set by using IDE, you probably able to quickly explore this option, but I assume it is not there and you want to do that by hand. In this case the simplest solution I can see is to create Custom Action (CA) and set "In-Script Execution" to "[Deferred Execution in System Context](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/isxhelp19/helplibrary/ActionExecutionOptions.htm)". By doing this you set elevated execution of this CA. Schedule this CA somewhere in [Execution Sequence](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/IHelpInstallationSequence.htm) (Not in UI sequence), probably right after "InstallServices". Now you have a few options what this CA should do. For example you may just use command line ["sc"](http://blogs.msmvps.com/erikr/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows/) to set desirable permissions. You may also write VBScript CA to do the same. You may write [installation helper dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637764/how-do-i-set-acl-for-a-windows-service-in-net) with would do registration for you. All in your hands. More on those option [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436558/start-stop-a-windows-service-from-a-non-administrator-user-account).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Still investigating. Will post an answer if it gets solved.